# PHP selected error

Tags: php

Me gustaría hacer un `selected` con la id que tengo en la variable. Estoy probando esto pero no me funciona, alguna idea? Gracias!

```
<option value="<?php echo $modali['id'] ?>" <?php selected($modali['id']) ?>><?php echo $modali['name'] ?></option>
```

Comment: De donde viene ese $modali? Es de una query a una base de datos? Necesitamos un poco mas de información. Si viene de una base de datos dinos que contienen las columnas, o como está montado. Gracias.

Comment: te sugiero revisar esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1336376/5215609

Comment: No entiendo muy bien. ¿Quieres que si el valor del ID es igual a un cierto valor ese option quede seteado como `selected`?  ¿Contra qué valor lo quieres comparar?